# c++ class member variable of the nested template type

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to create a templated class (`C2`), using as a template a class which is also templated (`C1`). Moreover in `C2` create a variable of the same type, which was used as template of the class `C1`.

```
template <typename Ttype>
class C1{
public:
    Ttype var;
}

template<class T> //class T always templated
class C2{
public:
    T x;
//  ? y; << variable of template type of the class T
}

int main()
{
    C1<int>  instanceInt;
    C1<long> instanceLong;
    
    C2<C1<int>> foo; //C2.y should be int
}
```

My initial implementation of the class `C2` was as follows, however it results in `error: identifier "Ttype" is undefined`. **Why doesn't compiler see the Ttype?**

```
template <template <class Ttype> class Tparam>
class C2 {

public:
    Tparam<Ttype> x;
    const Ttype y;
};
```

So my working, but not so nice solution is using a typedef.

```
template <typename Ttype>
class C1{
public:
    typedef Ttype Ctype
    Ttype var;
}

template<class T>
class C2{
public:
    typedef typename T::Ctype Ttype;
    T x;
    Ttype y;
}
```

I expect that there should be a better implementation of the same feature. Is there?

Comment: Your "working, but not so nice solution" is, in fact, the standard design for this. Perhaps you've heard of `std::vector<T>::iterator`, and perhaps you might be familiar with, say, `std::begin` giving you back the passed-in container's iterator class, whether or not what gets passed in is a vector, a list, or some other container. How do you suppose all of that works?

Answer (score 1):

The second approach could be fixed, however, the third is not bad either.

```
template <typename Ttype>
class C1
{
public:
    Ttype var;
};

template<template <class Ttype> class Tparam, typename T>
class C2
{
public:
    Tparam<T> x;
    T y;
};

void foo()
{
    C2<C1,int> bar;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use template specialization

```
template <typename>
class C2;

template <template <typename> class C, typename T>
class C2<C<T>>
 {
   public: 
      C<T> x;
      T    y;
 };
```

or you can also develop a custom type trait to extract a template argument from a type

```
template <typename>
struct get_tmpl_param;

template <template <typename> class C, typename T>
struct get_tmpl_param<C<T>>
 { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
using get_tmpl_param_t = typename get_tmpl_param<T>::type;
```

so your class `C2` (without specialization) can be

```
template <typename T>
class C2
 {
   public:
      T                    x;
      get_tmpl_param_t<T>  y;
 };
```